# if else in not operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to do this:

> Declare a variable called programming and set it to false. Then, write
>   an if/else statement inside happy so that happy returns true if
>   programming is false and false otherwise.

My code:

```
var programming = false;

var happy = function() {

  if (programming=!true ){
      return true
      }
  else
  {return true}
};
```

The error I'm getting:

> Oops, try again. It looks like your happy function returns true
>   instead of true when programming is true

Comment: ```else return false```?

Comment: Ignore the IF... `return !programming;`

Comment: Also note that the "not equal" operator is `!=`, not `=!`. What your `if (programming=!true)` is doing is **setting** `programming` to `false`.

Comment: First try to keep a good indentation in your code. For compare use `!=` instead of `=!` . In your else statement return false.

Comment: const happy = () => !programming

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9fb5ux80/1/

Comment: `programming=!true ` wrong syntax it should be `programming != true `

Comment: thanks Alexis, its fixed after use != instead of =!,

Comment: Thnks  @T.J. Crowder

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This question has nothing to do with php, jquery, angular, or HTML5.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've been explicitly told to use an `if`/`else` structure, the issues are:

1. You're using `=!` instead of `!=` to do the comparison. `if (programming=!true)` **sets** `programming` to `false` and then tests the result (which is `false`). You want to test the value. One lesson here is that it's poor practice to use `==` or `!=` to test booleans; just test the boolean itself.
2. You're returning `true` in both branches.

So:

```
var programming = false;

var happy = function() {

  if (!programming) {   // Fix #1
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;     // Fix #2
  }
};
```

Also note the importance of consistent, fairly standard indentation and bracing. (Though of course, you can do what you like in your own code, it's best when asking for help to use one of the many fairly-standard ways.)

Of course, `if`/`else` is not the best way to do this, but presumably the point of the exercise is to learn to code `if`/`else` structures. But just for completeness, the best way to do this is just to return a negated `programming`:

```
var happy = function() {
    return !programming;
};
```

---

(I also take issue with the idea that `happy` equates to `!programming`! ;-) I quite like programming...)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
var happy = function() {

  return !programming;

};
```

Comment: ...except, of course, that the assignment the OP is doing explicitly told them to use `if`/`else` (presumably in order to learn to use `if`/`else`).